# Excel issue- I Need a fillable date based on another date minus 14 days

Tags: excel

Good day everyone,

Some background
This is my first post and hope to learn what I can.
I have an excel sheet for work I created. It's a client list for cases going to court.
I have an ABA code currently running for multiple drop-down selections that I require for documents a client submits (this saves columns from going too far right into AA section.

My issue.
I have a date the court date is scheduled

[image]

I need Column H to populate minus 14 days based on column G entry.

So with Monday April 19 2021, I need H to automatically populate Monday, April 5th 2021.  Worst case scenario if I Can get April 5 2021 that would be ok to work with.

Comment: `=G2-14` and then apply a custom number format like `dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy`

Comment: Awesome, got that to work, now my only problem is the cells below H (not yet filled) have marks, how would I get Colum H to be blank as it depends on Column G?

Comment: `=IF(G2="","",G2-14)`?

Comment: Thank you this seems to work.